# IntelliJ IDEA disable font increase/decrease on CMD+scroll

Tags: fonts, size, intellij-idea, command, scroll

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2 on Mac OS X - with the Magic Mouse. Whenever I press the command button and move my finger a micrometer or two on the surface of the mouse, IDEA immediately increases or decreases my font size rapidly. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`Settings` | `Editor` | `Enable Ctrl+MouseWheel changes font size`

(On **Mac** it would be `Preferences` | `Editor` | `General` | `Enable CMD+MouseWheel changes font size`.)

Comment: Seriously, one of the few things I actually curse out load about with Idea.  Can't believe its still the default. Just cause you CAN do something doesn't mean you SHOULD.

Comment: In RubyMine 5.4 (Mac) the menu is `Preferences` | `Editor` | `Change font size (Zoom) with Command+Mouse Wheel`

Comment: On Mac, for version 2016.3.3 community edition, the setting was in `Preferences | Editor | General`. Edited the original answer.

Comment: On MacBook the scaling is done with **Command Key** + **two fingers** dragging. Up to shrink text and down to increase text size.

Answer (score 5):

**IntelliJ IDEA 14.1**

By default it is **disabled** and it can be found here:

File > Settings... > Editor > General > Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel

[image]
[image]

The option is still there in **IntelliJ IDEA 15** EAP.

Answer (score 2):

in Linux, before IDEA 11 i used Ctrl+ScrollWheel for change font size but now in IDEA 11 this feature has been removed

Comment: Ummm, this should help: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/zooming-in-the-editor.html