# Disable text zooming in RubyMine 4

Tags: rubymine

I have recently installed RubyMine 4.0 , which allows you to increase or decrease the text size by scrolling up or down while holding the command key. But what is happening for me is that AFTER scrolling I can press the command key and it is as if the inertia of the scroll is still going and in combination with the control key being pressed down is resizing my text.

There is a strong chance that this will get resolved in a patch, but is there a way I can disable the zooming feature for now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Idea disable font increase/decrease on CMD+scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483125/intellij-idea-disable-font-increase-decrease-on-cmdscroll)

Comment: Although the steps are the same, IntelliJ is a completely different product and I didn't find that while searching for a solution to my problem.

Comment: RubyMine is based on IntelliJ IDEA platform, so IDEA is the same product, but with more features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be disabled in RubyMine exactly the same way as it is disabled in IntelliJ:

```
Settings | Editor | Enable Ctrl+MouseWheel changes font size
```

[IntelliJ IDEA disable font increase/decrease on CMD+scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483125/intellij-idea-disable-font-increase-decrease-on-cmdscroll)

Comment: Is there a way to sett up a hotkey to zoom text?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Ctrl-Mousewheel on an Apple Magic Mouse and it didn't work, but Fn-Command-MouseWheel worked where MouseWheel is sliding your finger up or down the mouse).